# trigger to populate child field from parent object using relationship query from "parent to child"

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-chatter

We have two standard objects  account(parent) and contact (child ). i want to write a trigger to populate the lastname field of contact with the name field of account

The trigger below performs the same task but soql query is from child to parent .

I want the trigger which performs the same work but using soql query ( relationship query )   from parent to child .

```
trigger trgSetLastName on Contact (after insert) 
{
List<Contact> lstConUpdate = new List<Contact>();
List<Contact> lstContact = [select id,Account.Name from Contact where 
id in:  trigger.newmap.keyset()];
for(Contact con: lstContact)
{
    con.LastName = con.Account.Name;
    lstConUpdate.add(con);
}
if(lstConUpdate.size() > 0){
    update lstConUpdate;
}
}
```

i want a trigger for this .help

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.
Build a `Set<id>` of Account Ids:

```
for (Contact c : trigger.new){
    acctIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
}
```

Step 2. 
Select related Accounts into a `Map<Id,Account>` using:

```
[SELECT {fields}
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN :acctIdSet];
```

Step 3. 
Loop through `trigger.new` and extract the corresponding Account from your Map.

Step 4.
Update the LastName value on contact with the value on your Account - assuming it exists.

Step 5. 
Make your trigger fire before insert:

```
trigger trgSetLastName on Contact (before insert, before update)
```